# Use base64 with background url in email

Tags: jquery, email, gmail, html-email

I have a newsletter builder that allows users to upload their images on it. Every image is converted to base64 when is sent to emails.

Using `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j…1">` tag works fine.

The result in Gmail was: `<img src="cid:a92d6c4bca1c012c2e95bc6539b69130">`

However trying to use `background: url('base64_value')` does not work.

When showing original email, background url comes as `background: url('data:image/webp;base64..">`

Whats the difference between src and background url? Why with img base64 is working fine and with background url base64 is nor working? Is there a solution for it?

**jquery for background url:**

```
 reader.onload = function (e) {
     big_parent.css("background", "url(" + e.target.result + ")");      
 };
 reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

**jquery for src**

```
reader.onload = function (e) {
  big_parent.children('img').attr("src", e.target.result);
};
reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

Comment: It can be server-settings problem, for example your URI in src can be to long, and apache can throwing error, see more [there](https://wiki.iphoster.net/wiki/Apache_-_414_Request-URI_Too_Long)

Comment: base64 is a poor format to begin with. It's not widely supported. Also background-image doesn't have full support: https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-background-image/

Comment: Thank you guys from replying. Since this is my first Newsletter Builder project, I noticed a lot of limits on it, it's kind of frustrating. I decided to move on by now. Maybe forward with more knowledge I will build a professional Email Builder following correct alternatives.